# Issues in Doctrine ORM usage in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine

I have installed Doctrine in my ZendFramework application and kept it in the Library folder of the application. But when I try to run the application, I am getting the following error:

> Warning: require_once(Doctrine/Doctrine.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/square-06/application/Bootstrap.php on line 7 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Doctrine/Doctrine.php' (include_path='/var/www/square-06/application/../library:/var/www/square-06/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/square-06/application/Bootstrap.php on line 7

Is there any thing more that I have to do after extracting Doctrine into my application?

I have used the following link to install doctrine [Bisna Doctrine2 enabled ZF1 skeleton project](https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/zendframework1-doctrine2) from Github.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in your ..\library\Doctrine directory and see if Doctrine.php is actually there. I doubt that it is.

I have a skeleton that I use: https://github.com/bubba-h57/secret-skeleton

and if you look at the (https://github.com/bubba-h57/secret-skeleton/blob/master/public/index.php) file you will see where I set up some paths to ensure that Doctrine can be found and auto-loaded. Something like this:

```
// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
|| define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
|| define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

 // Define path to Zend library directory
defined('ZEND_LIB_PATH')
|| define('ZEND_LIB_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) .    '/../library/vendor/zend/framework/1.11.12/library'));

// Define path to the user library directory
defined('USER_LIB_PATH')
|| define('USER_LIB_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../library'));

// Define path to the user resource directory
defined('USER_RES_PATH')
|| define('USER_RES_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../resources'));

// Define path to the zf1-doctrine2 library directory
defined('ZF1D2_LIB_PATH')
|| define('ZF1D2_LIB_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../library/vendor/zf1-d2/library'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
ZEND_LIB_PATH,
USER_LIB_PATH,
ZF1D2_LIB_PATH,
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
APPLICATION_ENV,
APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()
        ->run();
```

You may also want to look at:
http://www.thecodehouse.com/2011/03/25/installing-doctrine-orm-in-a-zend-framework-application/
http://phphints.wordpress.com/2011/07/10/getting-bisna-to-work-with-doctrinecommon-2-1-0/

Comment: The path where Doctrine.php is located is :`/var/www/square-06/library/Doctrine/library/ZFDoctrine/Application/Resource`
Should i specify this path anywhere or change anywhere , please tell

Comment: I updated the answer with two additional links that were helpful to me when I first got started integrating Doctrine into Zendframework. The fact that your in an application/resource directory indicates you are configuring a plugin of sort. I'm not sure how to help you, do you have a github link where I could see the entire project layout and config?

Comment: Here is the code , please view it and add /delete folders ,that you feel are necessary `https://github.com/Zendy4009/secret-octo-wight`

Comment: I reckon you can just delete _initDoctrine() from your bootstrap. You are using the Bisna plugin, which will bootstrap itself. Otherwise, I don't see anything else that just jumps out at me.

Comment: Now this is the warning it's showing,if i try to access the search catalog option :
Warning: include_once(Doctrine/Query.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/square-06/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Doctrine/Query.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/square-06/application/../library:/var/www/square-06/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/square-06/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146 Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine_Query' not found in /var/www/square-06/library/Square/Form/ItemCreate.php on line 206

Comment: .Its not able to recognise this line , do i need to change anything more    " $q = Doctrine_Query::create()"

Comment: @RockyFord , Sir please go through the code and see if you can help me `https://github.com/Zendy4009/secret-octo-wight`

Comment: please anwer the  question :.Its not able to recognise this line , do i need to change anything more " $q = Doctrine_Query::create()"